# Why doesn't this Ajax form submission work?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

What is wrong with the following code?

The alert returns success but nothing is added to the table. The form:

```
<form id="Form_1" name="theform" method="post" action="">
    <label for="email" class="emailLab">Email * </label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email_id" autocorrect placeholder="Email" value="" />
    <label for="phone">Phone </label>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone_id" autocorrect placeholder="Phone" />
    <input type="image" src="images/btn_enter.png" height="26" width="147" id="submit" data-inline="true" data-role="none" />
</form>
```

On submit I call this function:

```
function serverDB (){
    // Define variables from input
    var vEmail = document.getElementById('email_id').value;
    var vPhone = document.getElementById('phone_id').value;

    var theData = 'email=' + vEmail + '&phone=' +vPhone;
    alert (theData);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: theData,
        success: function(){
            alert ("Success");
        }
    });
}
```

And the PHP code:

```
<?
    $email  = $_POST['email'];
    $phone  = $_POST['phone'];
    mysql_connect("host", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("sandbox_itouch") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `data` (email, phone) VALUES ('$email','$phone')");
?>
```

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem but consider using [PDO](http://www.php.net/PDO) or [mysqli](http://www.php.net/mysqli) if they are available to you. Use prepared statements to protect from [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a '=' on this line after the "&phone" :

```
 var theData = 'email=' + vEmail + '&phone' +vPhone;
```

It may be a typo.

Comment: oops thanks that was a typo.. not like that in my real code and not the problem.. i updated my question

Comment: actually.. among about 10 other problems this did turn out to be one of them...  Thanks!

Comment: These kinds of small stupid mistakes almost always gets me ;) You're welcome !

Answer (score 1):

Check that the $_POST values are reaching your script and that your MySQL connection is working as expected and your column and table names match the database.

You can create logs like this

```
$fh = fopen('log.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fh, print_r($_POST, true));
fclose($fh);
```

If log.txt isn't created you will know that the script isn't getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

Add logging to your code to see if your server-side script is even running, how far it's getting, what data it's getting, and what errors it's seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the input... can you provide a noob with some more help with this?  I changed my php to have the mysql_connect into a $con variable and then if (!$con)
{die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());} can you please show me what other logging I should add?

Comment: Add error_log("*001"); and error_log("*002"); etc. between every line. Then watch your error log (find it!) and see what is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your data type to JSON or specify the data type explicitly when posting:

```
var theData = '{ email:' + vEmail + ', phone:' + vPhone + '}' ;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process.php",
    data: theData,
    success: function(){
        alert ("Success");
        $().innerHTML =
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the idea.. tried that but still no luck